# How to refer to the array without changing its' contents

Tags: javascript, arrays

How am I able to write this so that I do not change the order of myApp.myArr2 and only refer to it instead?

I want the 2nd last line to produce 'hello world' and the last line to produce 'world hello'

```
myApp.myArr2 = ["hello", "world"];

function reverseArray(temp) {
myApp.myNewArr2 = temp.reverse();
};

reverseArray(myApp.myArr2);

console.log(myApp.myArr2); // world hello
console.log(myApp.myNewArr2); // world hello
```

Comment: what programming language is that?

Comment: Hi - I am using JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Change the line from:

```
myApp.myNewArr2 = temp.reverse();
```

to

```
myApp.myNewArr2 = temp.slice().reverse();
```

A JSFiddle link example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jb7p7un5/).

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.reverse make reverse array in-place. This is true. If you want to get copy you can do it with following code:

```
function reverseCopy(array) {
     var copy = [];
     array.forEach(function(e) { copy.unshift(e); });
     return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a copy of an array you can do:

```
var newArray = oldArray.slice();
```